# ReactAdmin doesn't fully recognize a custom Resource functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I want to DRY the way my `<Resource />` components are organized in my project. This way, my `App.jsx` file won't be bloated by a lot of code.

For example, let's say I have a `<EmployeeResource />` component like this:

```js
// ./resources/Employee.jsx

import React from "react";
import { Resource } from "react-admin";

const EmployeeResource = (props) => <Resource {...props} name="employees" />;

export default EmployeeResource;
```

Now I want to use it in my `<Admin />` component like this:

```js
// ./App.jsx

// other imports
import EmployeeResource from "./resources/Employee";

const App = () => (
  <Admin
    {...otherNecessaryProps}
  >
    <EmployeeResource />
  </Admin>
);
```

Even if it's registered by `react-admin` and that I can see its link in the sidebar, its route doesn't work. If I click on the menu item I see a *Not Found* page, but if I navigate to `/undefined` in my browser, now I see its content.

Is there a way to DRY many `<Resource />` components in one sub folder?